# Como desabilito via Javascript que os cookies carreguem dados em apenas uma página especifica

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, formulário, cookies

Tenho uma pagina de cadastro que possui email e senha, quando o usuario clica em guardar email e senha no login, o auto preenchimento dos coockies ja preenchem os dados do cadastro. Eu nao posso limpar o coockie e eles tem q funcionar normalmente nas outras paginas. (eu ja tentei usar autocomplete="off" no html mas nao funcionou, e eu tambem nao posso tornar null o email e senha pois quando o navegador busca os coockies dispara uma validaçao).

Comment: Coloque aqui um excerto do seu código fonte e tente melhorar um pouco o conteúdo da sua pergunta.